# Problem downloading a dataset from a wlatin1 environment to a UTF-8 one

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, sas

I'm downloading (with a `proc download` in SAS) a dataset from a server with wlatin1 encoding to a server with UTF-8 encoding.

I've got the error

```
ERROR: Some character data was lost during transcoding in the data set
       libref.datasetname. Either the data contains characters that are not
       representable in the new encoding or truncation occurred during transcoding.
```

I tried setting `inencoding='utf8'` or `inencoding='asciiany'` on the input dataset but it doesn't work (maybe because the wlatin1 server has SAS 9.3 whereas the UTF-8 server has SAS 9.4).

Rewriting the file like in the following code (and then doing the `proc download` of `myoutput`) works, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do the same thing.

```
data myoutput;
set pathin.myinput;
/*Translittera la I accentata con I normale*/
des_nome = tranwrd(des_nome,'CD'x,'I');
des_nome = tranwrd(des_nome,'ED'x,'i');
/*Translittera la A accentata con A normale*/
des_nome = tranwrd(des_nome,'C1'x,'A');
des_nome = tranwrd(des_nome,'E1'x,'a');
/*Translittera la E accentata con E normale*/
des_nome = tranwrd(des_nome,'C9'x,'E');
des_nome = tranwrd(des_nome,'E9'x,'e');
/*Translittera la O accentata con O normale*/
des_nome = tranwrd(des_nome,'D2'x,'O');
des_nome = tranwrd(des_nome,'D3'x,'O');
des_nome = tranwrd(des_nome,'D6'x,'O');
des_nome = tranwrd(des_nome,'F3'x,'o');
/*Translittera la U accentata con U normale*/
des_nome = tranwrd(des_nome,'DC'x,'U'); 
des_nome = tranwrd(des_nome,'F9'x,'u'); 
/*Translittera la Y accentata con Y normale*/
des_nome = tranwrd(des_nome,'DD'x,'Y');
des_nome = tranwrd(des_nome,'FD'x,'y');
/*Translittera accenti strani con '*/
des_nome = tranwrd(des_nome,'B4'x,"'");
/*Translittera simboli strani con spazi*/
des_nome = tranwrd(des_nome,'A7'x,' ');  /* § nel NOME */
des_nome = tranwrd(des_nome,'A3'x,' ');  /* £ nel NOME */
cod_cap_res = tranwrd(cod_cap_res,'A3'x,' '); /* £ nel CAP */
run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this SAS macro `%copy_to_utf8` which will convert your data to UTF8 automatically.
https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/nlsref/p1f9ghftk3fgrin16t57ub6svmet.htm

`%copy_to_utf8(pathin.myinput, myoutput)`

Comment: If you pull in the dataset using proc download and then convert it on the UTF-8 server then it should work.

Comment: Does it give this error with the `binary` option?

Comment: Great. If you do a binary download and then convert to UTF-8 on the server with that macro, you should have success. This should be the same as manually sending the file over using something like `rsync`.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is that the storage length of at least one of the variables in original dataset is too short to fit the expanded length required by the UTF-8 representation of at least one of the strings.

Here is simple way to demonstrate the problem.  Create a simple file with all 256 possible characters of the WLATIN1 (or LATIN1) encoding.

```
340  %put %sysfunc(getoption(encoding,keyword));
ENCODING=WLATIN1
341  data 'c:\downloads\wlatin1.sas7bdat';
342    string = collate(0,256);
343  run;

NOTE: The data set c:\downloads\wlatin1.sas7bdat has 1 observations and 1 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds
```

Now try to read it in a session using UTF-8 encoding.  Even if you make the variable longer in the output dataset the conversion fails.

```
38   data test1;
39     length string $1024;
40     set 'c:\downloads\wlatin1.sas7bdat';
NOTE: Data file WC000001.WLATIN1.DATA is in a format that is native to another host, or the file encoding does not match the
      session encoding. Cross Environment Data Access will be used, which might require additional CPU resources and might reduce
      performance.
41   run;

ERROR: Some character data was lost during transcoding in the dataset WC000001.WLATIN1. Either the data contains characters that
       are not representable in the new encoding or truncation occurred during transcoding.
NOTE: The DATA step has been abnormally terminated.
NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
WARNING: The data set WORK.TEST1 may be incomplete.  When this step was stopped there were 0 observations and 1 variables.
WARNING: Data set WORK.TEST1 was not replaced because this step was stopped.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.01 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds
```

So to fix that read the file using ENCODING='ANY' and then convert the strings from WLATIN1 to UTF-8.

```
42   data test;
43     length string $1024;
44     set 'c:\downloads\wlatin1.sas7bdat' (encoding='any');
45     string = kcvt(string,'wlatin1','utf-8');
46   run;

NOTE: There were 1 observations read from the data set c:\downloads\wlatin1.sas7bdat.
NOTE: The data set WORK.TEST has 1 observations and 1 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.01 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have better luck letting the newer version of SAS that is running with UTF-8 encoding do the transcoding instead of forcing the remote libref engine to attempt to deal with it.

So if you wanted to download the dataset MYLIB.MYDATA you could first copy the actual dataset file.  Then transcode it.

```
%syslput lwork=%qsysfunc(pathname(work));
rsubmit;
  proc download binary infile="%sysfunc(pathname(MYLIB))/mydata.sas7bdat"
     outfile="&lwork/mydata.sas7bdat" ;
  run;
endrsubmit;
data mydata; 
  set mydata(encoding='wlatin1');
run;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I get the same error as before on the last data step.

Comment: Run proc contents on the dataset and confirm the encoding that it is actually using.  There should not be any WLATIN1 code that cannot transcode into UFT-8.  But if you are trying to go the other way there are plenty of problems.  And if it is trying to interpret a file as if it already had UTF-8 encoded strings but they were instead WLATIN1 or some other single byte encoding there could be combinations that are not valid UTF-8 strings.

Comment: The proc contents says `Encoding             latin1  Western (ISO)`

Comment: It would be very strange to not be able to read it using a session that is running with system encoding of UTF-8.  Double check the setting of the system option ENCODING for the SAS session that is trying to read it.

Comment: Running `%put _all_;` I get `AUTOMATIC SYSENCODING utf-8`. However, the macro suggested by Stu Sztukowski works.